# TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received True

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to query GAE datastore with a list of possible values. something like:

```
list_of_assigned_therapists = [ ... ]
qry = Appointment.query(Appointment.therapist in list_of_assigned_therapists)
```

but I get the error in the title. the only refernce I found is when using properties not declared in the model. but my model looks like

```
class Appointment(BaseModel):
    therapist = ndb.KeyProperty(MyUser, required = True)
    Patient = ndb.KeyProperty(MyUser)
    when = TZDateTimeProperty(required = True)
    status = ndb.IntegerProperty(default = 1)
```

and simple queries

```
qry = Appointment.query(Appointment.therapist == selected_therapist_key)
```

works fine, no error what so ever.

what am I doing wrong ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'in' clause is not used as you are doing. You need to do this:

```
qry = Appointment.query(Appointment.therapist.IN(list_of_assigned_therapists))
```

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in).